# Importing multiple contacts into address book iOS6\Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

Main Issue:

I have created an application that contains a directory of people in three tabs (by location, specialty, and name). The person can select a contact in the application and call them; however, the phone receiving the call show's only a number and not a name (as the contacts are not in the address book, but inside an sqlite db in my app).

Work around:

I'm not quite sure if there are any other way's to get around the issue, but since both the calling and receiving phone's will have the application installed, my work around was to import the contacts from my sqlite3 database (or array the database is being pulled into) into the iPhones address book. Once in the iPhone's address book when a person calls it will show a name instead of a number.

The Issue:

I can find documentation for adding a single contact to the address book, but not adding multiple people (the database currently holds about 150 contacts). I thought about trying to do a loop, but I really dont know where to start.. Can anyone help lead me to the right way to get this done :)

Also what would be the best way to do this in the background so that it does not cause the application to pause\freeze.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int index = 0 ; index< ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBookObj); index++)
{
    recordRefObj = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(arrayRefObj, index);
    NSString *nameStr = (__bridge NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue(recordRefObj, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    [nameArray addObject:nameStr];
}
```